# In JavaScript what is better to put config constants in same module file or a separate config file

Tags: javascript

This is more of a question regarding the architecture of an application, let's say you have a module `something.js` with some kind of special configuration constants mind you that these constants are hardcoded they are not imported from `env` or some file.

Would it be better to put everything related to this module as a global constant or is it better to import all configuration constants from `config.js` for example.

I'm interested in knowing the pros and cons from an architecture point of view.

Answer (score 1):

If it's something high-level or broad, like a `debug` option that turns on debug output across your app, I would be inclined to put it in a common config file. On the other hand, if it's something specific or narrowly scoped, like how many characters a particular piece of text can be before it's truncated, I would be inclined to keep it in the only file that references it.